# Detect two bitmap's hit

Tags: android

Hey i am making a game that you are a spaceship and enemys are falling on you so far i have made the spaceship shoot and the
enemy falling fron the top of the screen (i have already made that if the bullet hits the enemy you get points)

but i have one problem that im stuck on for 2 days already the problem is to detect spaceship and enemy hit (they hit each other) 
when they hitting each other it works but also when they far away from each other..

the code of the hit check is

```
if(invaders.getx0()-(iwidth/2)>=this.x-(pwidth/2)&&invaders.getx0()+iwidth<=this.x+pwidth&&invaders.gety0()+iheight>this.y&&invaders.gety0()<=this.y) {
    invaders.setbitmap(1);
}
```

it checks if enemy 0 hitted the spaceship
iwidth is the enemy bitmap width
iheight is enemy bitmap height
pwidth is spaceship bitmap width
pheight is spaceship bitmap height

this.x and this.y is spaceship x and y
invaders.getx0 and invaders.gety0 is the enemy x and y

and invaders.setbitmap() is to set the life
please help me thanks

Comment: Why don't you use `Rectangle` for the hit detection? I think that would simplify your calculations a lot. Rectangles already provide a `intersect` method. I don't want to post this as answer since I don't really know anything about your project and there might be a reason why you calculate all of this yourself.

Comment: I didnt knew that about rectangles can you send me a link to how to do what you said?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Rect` to detect intersections. For example you can describe the location and size of the objects on screen with `Rect` like this:

```
Rect rect1 = new Rect(0, 0, 100, 10);
Rect rect2 = new Rect(20, 0, 10, 10);
```

And when you want to check if they intersect you just call `intersect`:

```
if(rect1.intersect(rect2)) {
    // Rectangles intersect  
} else {
    // Rectangles don't intersect
}
```

Comment: Ohh ok but the bitmaps are round so there can be a situation that it will detect intersect in wrong position of the bitmap (the edges of the rect)

Comment: I realise that, but the code you posted in your question also doesn't account for that so I assumed it's ok.

Comment: Ok but how can i put my bitmap on the rect and make the rect transparent (that only the bmp will appear without background)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? `Rect` just contain 2 coordinates. `Rect` don't hold any graphical information. You can use them to hold the position and size of `Bitmaps`, but the `Rects` themselves don't influence the drawing of those `Bitmaps` aside from that.

Comment: Ohhhh now i understood what you mean ok i will try that!

Comment: Ok i tried it and it worked! But suddenly the ememys are not moving smoothly as before why?

Comment: Off the top of my head I would guess it is because of integer/float conversions. Do you account for that? You can use `RectF` to store float values. I think `Rect` only stores integers.

Comment: I casted the floats to int

Comment: Try using `RectF` instead of `Rect`. And only use floats throughout your app. Or at least for all your calculations.